# Basic mail function (PHP) additional "-f" parameter question

Tags: php, email, function, sendmail

Is the `-f` additional parameter correctly set in this mail function.

```
@mail("example@exmaple.com.uy",$title,$body,$headers,"-f");
```

I am Getting the `X Warning` from some servers.

Sorry for the basic question but some parts of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) got me confused (specially some user comments).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the manual:

> The additional_parameters parameter
>   can be used to pass additional flags
>   as command line options to the program
>   configured to be used when sending
>   mail, as defined by the sendmail_path
>   configuration setting. For example,
>   this can be used to set the envelope
>   sender address when using sendmail
>   with the -f sendmail option.
>
> The user that the webserver runs as
>   should be added as a trusted user to
>   the sendmail configuration to prevent
>   a 'X-Warning' header from being added
>   to the message when the envelope
>   sender (-f) is set using this method.
>   For sendmail users, this file is
>   /etc/mail/trusted-users.

source: http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Sending-Mail-Php39s-Mail-Function_t2728.html

> The additional_parameters parameter
>   can be used to pass an additional
>   parameter to the program configured to
>   use when sending mail using the
>   sendmail_path configuration setting.
>   For example, this can be used to set
>   the envelope sender address when using
>   sendmail with the -f sendmail option.
>   You may need to add the user that your
>   web server runs as to your sendmail
>   configuration to prevent a 'X-Warning'
>   header from being added to the message
>   when you set the envelope sender using
>   this method. Example 3. Sending mail
>   with extra headers and setting an
>   additional command line parameter.

i.e:

```
<?php
mail("nobody@example.com", "the subject", $message,
"From: webmaster@{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}", "-fwebmaster@{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}");
?>
```

After -f you need to set the outgoing email address to prevent the warning (in this case its webmaster@-the domain-

Answer (score 2):

If your machine runs on a linux server. Your apache install more than likely runs under the user 'www-data'.

you can figure this out easily by going to /etc/apache2 and typing

```
cat envvars | grep APACHE_RUN_USER
```

whatever is after '=' is what user apache is running as.

You need to add this user to the trusted-users file. This file is located at /etc/mail/trusted-users

just

```
nano /etc/mail/trusted-users
```

and write 'www-data'.

save and you should be good to go.

Comment: Apache doesn't need to be restarted.

Comment: After this, should the flag point to www-data? `'-fwww-data'`

Answer (score 1):

-f should be followed by the address you want as envelope address on your mail.

```
@mail("example@exmaple.com.uy",$title,$body,$headers,"-fexample@exmaple.com.uy");
```

Comment: Ok I´m giving this a try. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending it without the -f flag?

> The user that the webserver runs as
>   should be added as a trusted user to
>   the sendmail configuration to prevent
>   a 'X-Warning' header from being added
>   to the message when the envelope
>   sender (-f) is set using this method.
>   For sendmail users, this file is
>   /etc/mail/trusted-users.

Comment: Yes I have tried and this was supposedly what got the emails bouncing from one particular server.

Comment: They were bouncing because they had no from address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an email address after the -f flag. Like this: "-fexample@example.com". You may also need to add the user that your web server run as to your sendmail configuration.