# Change the sender name php mail instead of sitename@hostname.com

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I am trying to send email from my php :

```
$to = 'it@7sisters.in';
    $email_from = "info@7sisters.in";

    $full_name = 'Suraj Hazarika';
    $from_mail = $full_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';



    $subject = "testing sender name";
    $message = "";
    $message .= '
            <p><strong>This is only a test . Please do not reply.</strong><br />
    ';
    $from = $from_mail;

    $headers = "" .
               "Reply-To:" . $from . "\r\n" .
               "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";        
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I am following the tutorial [PHP E-mail Form Sender Name Instead Of E-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728361/php-e-mail-form-sender-name-instead-of-e-mail) but I am still getting the emails with sender name with hostname.

```
     From                              Date             Subject 
sisters@rsx02.justhost.com  Fri, 11:24 pm       testing sender name
sisters@rsx02.justhost.com  Fri, 11:24 pm       testing sender name
```

Comment: You might want to look into header injections attacks. Your code isn't directly vulnerable but be sure to look out for it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You only use `$from` in your `Reply-To` header.  If you want it to be in the `From` header, you need to set it in the `From` header.

Put something like this before your `mail()` command:

```
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the `From` address that is being set here is not the same as the "envelope sender" address. In order to prevent emails not being delivered it's worth setting both.

Answer (score 30):

I came to this question looking for something different but with similar words, so here's how to do what I was looking for:

In the `from` header, put the address in angle brackets, and the "sender name" outside of it.

```
from: Don Draper <don.draper@website.com>\n
```

I wanted the inbox to say `Don Draper` instead of `don.draper` and that's how to do it.

Answer (score 12):

Add this line before header line

```
$headers .= "From: Your Name <sitename@hostname.com> \r\n";
```

So the code will be

```
$headers = "";
$headers .= "From: WIFI Metropolis <sitename@hostname.com> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:" . $from . "\r\n" ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";        
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also try adding the `From` address to the mail's 'envelope' by utilizing the fifth parameter in PHP's `mail()` function:

```
mail($to_mail, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f$from_email");
```

Reference [here](http://thesystemadministrator.net/cpanel/using-5th-parameter-in-php-mail-function-on-cpanel-server).

Reference regarding mail headers and envelopes [here](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/support/Setting_From_and_Bounce_Address_on_Email_From_Websites)

Note that some server setups may disallow this or throw a warning, depending on their configuration and/or the configuration of the mail transfer agent. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205261/988246) talks about updating sendmail's 'trusted users' with regards to this.

Comment: It's not forcing anything, the `From:` header sets the MIME sender, whereas `-f` additional parameter sets the envelope sender. This is disallowed in safe mode.

Comment: @LeonardChallis Quite right; I didn't fully understand the difference between headers and envelopes. I've updated my answer with a (hopefully) better, clearer explanation and references.

Comment: OMG.  I've been struggling for years with emails going to spam because the domain in the from header had proper DKIM/SPF records but the envelope domain was still default and did not.  You sir, just changed my life. Why more tutorials don't bring this up is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the From header. Something like this.

```
$headers .= "From: website@mydomainname.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `From:` to the header

```
$headers = "" .
           "Reply-To:" . $from . "\r\n" .
           "From:" . $from . "\r\n" .
           "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Some MTA can change/ignore this definition to avoid SPAM, and override with user of SMTP configured in PHP.ini