# PHP mail() how to set sender mail

Tags: php, email

This is my code:

```
$to = 'to@mail.com';

$subject = 'test';

$body = 'test';

$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header .= "To: <$to>" . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From: from@mail.com \r\n';

mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
```

The code works, it sends the email.
But the sender is not the one that I defined.
The sender seems to be the webmail host.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the sender name php mail instead of sitename@hostname.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365754/change-the-sender-name-php-mail-instead-of-sitenamehostname-com)

Comment: Try adding `Reply-to` with the same email address as the `From`.

Comment: By the way, the \r\n on your From header in the example above will not convert to a newline sequence, because you're using single quotes. Don't know if that's your whole problem but it probably isn't helping :)

Comment: the Reply-to worked, but now I get my mail account but not my host after the @. I still get the webmailhost. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using 's around the from bit. The \r\n become LITERALS. Try changing to `$header .= "From: from@mail.com\r\n";`

Comment: I changed it to $header .= "Reply-to: noreply@mydomainname.com\r\n";. But The mail I receive is from noreply@mywebhostdomainname.com.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try setting the envelope sender, as well setting the sender in the headers of the message, like so:

```
$to = "to@to.com";
$from = "from@from.com";
$subject = "subject";
$message = "this is the message body";

$headers = "From: $from"; 
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from);
```

Comment: This did not change anything. By changing my original code to $header .= "Reply-to: noreply@mydomainname.com\r\n";, I now receive the mail from 'noreply'. But the mail I receive is from noreply@mywebhostdomainname.com instead of noreply@mydomainname.com. Any Ideas?

Comment: Strange that this did not solve the problem.  In your php.ini, what are your settings for sendmail_from and sendmail_path?

Comment: I am using a paid host, I'm not sure how and if I can access php.ini

Comment: create a short php script like so, and this will show you all of the environment variables defined in php.ini:  

  <? phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: The settings are: sendmail_from - no value, sendmail_path - /usr/bin/sendmail -t -i

Comment: That's what they should be.  The code above should set the envelope sender and set the sender in the headers.  Can you try sending yourself another test message, and post the full source of the headers from the message that you receive, so we can see where noreply@mywebhostdomainname.com  is coming from?

Comment: using your code:

from: nobody@abc07.octosquid.com
to: my@mail.com
date: Fri, Jul 26, 2013 at 11:24 PM
subject: subject

Comment: Strange.  Maybe they are relaying outgoing messages through something else that is re-writing the headers.  You might want to work around this problem by sending your messages out through a remote SMTP server, instead of this local one.  You can do this easily using phpmailer.  It's simple to use and simple to setup - just three files to copy to your folder.  Then you can relay messages through any SMTP server that you have access to.  If you have a gmail account, then you can use smtp.gmail.com.  See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Thanks! PHPMailer did the trick. Everything is working fine now.