# Add 'From' Header on email using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, header, cpanel

I'm working with Codeigniter in CPanel and my code already sends a mail, but when it gets to the receiver, the hostname is shown on the sender. 
I tried some answer to questions as :  [Change the sender name php mail instead of sitename@hostname.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365754/change-the-sender-name-php-mail-instead-of-sitenamehostname-com) but in Codeigniter, they don't work.

This is my code:

```
 $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'ssmtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://ssmtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'mail@domainiwant.com', 
                'smtp_pass' => 'password',            
                'mailtype'  => 'html',
                'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
                'useragent' => 'MY NAME',
            );
            $this->load->library('email', $config); 
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('mail@domainiwant.com', 'MY NAME');

            $email_to = 'receiver@gmail.com';
            $this->email->to($email_to);

            $this->email->message('Message testing ...');
            $this->email->send();
```

However, as I said, when the mail gets to the receiver, they appear with the hostname and a completely different mail address like the one I put on `$config`

I know this only sets `the envelope sender` but I want to set the mail address to be `mail@domainiwant.com` instead of receiving the mail with `somemail@host.com.ex`

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server?? Please ask for it from service provider.

Comment: According to CI's own documentation, `$config['protocol']` should be set to `smtp`, not `ssmtp`. Since `ssmtp` is not an accepted value in the config, your code may be defaulting to the `mail` setting, which will attempt to deliver the mail using your own server as the sender instead of using your SMTP settings. Give it a try and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of CodeIgniter's email library available [HERE](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#email-preferences), your whole problem is a simple typo.

`$config['protocol']` allows `mail`, `sendmail` and `smtp` as values. If you don't set the variable, or use a value which is not allowed, the whole library defaults to `mail` which attempts to use your own server as the mail gateway (which explains why your sender address shows as `username@servername`)

Change the protocol from `ssmtp` to `smtp` so that you actually use the Google SMTP server you intend to use and you'll get the results you expect

Comment: Yeah that worked. I didn't realize I was using the wrong protocol