# PHP mail replaces explicit from sender@example.com with local hostname

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am currently having a struggle sending an email from PHP:

```
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "From: jan@example.com\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: jan@example.com\r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP " . phpversion();
mail("receiver@example.org", "Subject", "Body", $header);
```

The problem is that on receiver side, the mail has the sender address `xxx@example.net` (where `example.net` is the host the PHP script runs on).

`example.com` gets replaced by `example.net` all the time. I'm running Plesk and PHP 8.0.3. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think PHP is doing that, it might be your mailserver configuration.

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365754/change-the-sender-name-php-mail-instead-of-sitenamehostname-com

Comment: @oncodeeater Thank you, already tried that but didnt work. (<janXXX.at>)

Answer (score 3):

Turned out that plesk has a feature called "Fix incorrectly set sender for outgoing mail under Tools & Settings > Mail Server.

unchecked that, works.